# How do I use two wireless cards?

Tags: wireless

I want to set up  two wifi cards to work one connected to the internet and one connected to a non-internet network. What wifi cards should I use? And what router should I buy for the second network connection?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a usb wifi card ?! look for what you need it. extra programms ? look what chip you need to run the programm e.x Reaver-WPS